# Javascript how to reconstruct image from its contents

Tags: javascript, image, blob

I just uploaded a formdata image to a server. This server only returns to me the image's content. I tried wrapping it as a Blob, as a File, I tried fileReader... nothing works. I get this:[image]

the last thing I tried was

`const img = new Image(response.data);`

and then using this function:

```
const ImageDataToBlob = function(imageData){
    let w = imageData.width;
    let h = imageData.height;
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, w, h);        // synchronous

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            canvas.toBlob(resolve); // implied image/png format
    })
```

from here https://gist.github.com/Jonarod/77d8e3a15c5c1bb55fa9d057d12f95bd. But it didn't work either, since the function explode when running `ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, w, h);`.

How can I turn this into a valid `blob` object?

Comment: unless you send the correct image mime/content type i.e image/png then it is going to be corrupted, what you see is borked chars representing the bytes, thay are not the bytes

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how so?

Comment: "I just uploaded a formdata image to a server." - please show code. It might be broken at this stage.

Comment: Oh, I got it via postman and it returns the image properly

Comment: You must consume the response as a Blob, currently it's been consumed as UTF-8 text, and as said previously, some bits can't be represented as such and were thus "broken". You can't do much from that, you need to fix the part that does receive the response, and if you want us to help you fix that, you must show it to us.

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for your response, I'm sorry, that is the only think I can provide right now.